# Get SFDC sessionID via access token

Tags: salesforce-id, oauth2, java, oauth, session

As the title. I'm using username/password flow to request an access token. So how can I request a SFDC sessionID from that token?

Answer (score 2):

The access token plays the same role as the session ID. Essentially the access token is the session ID for your web service.

Comment: But the token get expire after a period of time, right?

Comment: That's right, so does the session ID. You can set the expiry time in Setup -> Security Controls -> Session Settings (Timeout Value)

Comment: As you said. I don't need to request for sessionID, right? If true, how can I work with access token like sessionID? Could you give me any example?

Comment: Once you get the access token you need to stick it to the authoization header `Authorization : OAuth YOURACCESSTOKEN` and then you can make subsequent callouts from your environment to SF. A good java (based on your tags) example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258653/salesforce-rest-api-login (DaSh's answer).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm practicing on the example you gave.